# xPath union statement with functions

Tags: xpath, union, data-extraction

thanks in advance for reading.

I'm using `$x()` xPath evaluator of Chrome console.

I need to match something shaped like `$x("e1 | e2")`.

In my case:

- e1:

  `(//div[@class='seven columns omega']//form//div[@class='items_left']//text())[2]`
- e2

  `(substring-after(//div[@class='seven columns omega']//span[@class='sold_out']/text(),' - '))`

They both works in the single way but if i want to combine them I just get stuck in

"Failed to execute 'evaluate'..."

**PS The problem is e2 function substring-after, without it the union works.**

Any Ideas?
Here are the 2 sources i'm trying to extract:

- [e1-case](https://www.fendrihan.com/products/japanese-bamboo-charcoal-facial-oil-blotting-paper)
- [e2-case](https://www.fendrihan.com/products/katana-tsuba-damascus-money-clip)

Thanks again :)

Comment: You can't use the union operator `|` on a string value, you can only compute the union of node-sets.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for reply. Good to know, approaching to xpath just few days ago. There are workaround that I may use for my purpouse?

Comment: What kind of result do you want, the concatenation of the two results? There is no much you can do with pure XPath but inside the Chrome console you use Javascript anyway so you can perhaps use `$x("(//div[@class='seven columns omega']//form//div[@class='items_left']//text())[2]") + $x("(substring-after(//div[@class='seven columns omega']//span[@class='sold_out']/text(),' - '))")`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen 
The attribute that i'm lookin for is expressed sometimes as in the e1 case: "In stock, ready to ship" with a certain xpath.

In other occurrence, case e2, it's showed other way: "- Sold Out
" with different xpath.

I would like to catch at least e1 or e2, they are mutual exclusive.
I just need to catch them both as the same attribute string.

Comment: As far as I know, within the Google Chrome console if you use `$x("(//div[@class='seven columns omega']//form//div[@class='items_left']//text())[2]")`, you get a Javascript array which is either empty or contains a single DOM text node. If you use `$x("(substring-after(//div[@class='seven columns omega']//span[@class='sold_out']/text(),' - '))")` you get a Javascript string value. The XPath 1.0 data model does not allow you to select both values with one XPath expression and within Javascript there is also no direct way to combine an array with a text node and a primitive string.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Very glad for your answers. If I have update I'll post it.
PS I'm intrested in string contents, not as array type. Guided by your comment i'll maybe try to concatenate them as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments that you want string values and expect only one of those expressions to find something on the same page you could simply try

```
var result = $x("string((//div[@class='seven columns omega']//form//div[@class='items_left']//text())[2])") + $x("(substring-after(//div[@class='seven columns omega']//span[@class='sold_out']/text(),' - '))")
```

Comment: Ahahah that's right! 
I just found this solution too! Thanks to your previous comments obvsiously :D
Actually works but i'm using "concat" function, instead of "+" operator, I really guess they both works.

Solved :)